# Apple Script help - how do I tell OS X to not launch a specific app during a specific time period?

Tags: applescript

How do I make an Apple Script (or something similar) that will tell OS X "do not launch/run (*n*) app from (*x1*) time to (*x2*) time?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following? It can be used as an app launcher. It doesn't stop the user of launching the app but for a child it should do. You could also easily convert it to a background script to continuously monitor for desired app and kill it once usage goes beyond allowed time block.

Hope it helped.

```
# The times to check. Use HH:MM:SS 24HR format or AM/PM
set sTime to "19:00:00" # 7PM
set eTime to "20:00:00" # 8PM

# Get just the date from shell; quicker
set tDate to getShortDate()

# Setup Date & Time vars for start and end
set sDateTime to tDate & " " & (sTime)
set eDateTime to tDate & " " & (eTime)

# Convert dates to Epoch
set sEpoch to toEpoch(sDateTime)
set eEpoch to toEpoch(eDateTime)

set epochNow to getEpoch()

if epochNow > sEpoch and epochNow < eEpoch then
    tell application "Finder" to set tProcesses to name of processes
    if (tProcesses contains "Firefox") then
        display dialog "Firefox is currently banned"
        #Kill Firefox app
    end if
else
    #log "Launching Firefox..."
    activate application "Firefox"
end if

on getEpoch()
    return do shell script "date \"+%s\""
end getEpoch

on toEpoch(aDateTime)
    return do shell script "date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %T' '" & aDateTime & "' +'%s'"
end toEpoch

on getShortDate()
    return do shell script "date \"+%Y-%m-%d\""
end getShortDate
```